# clang static analyzer

Tags: macos, command-line

I'd like to use scan-build. The official site says there are pre-built binaries for it, but fails to provide any links to them:
https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/installation

How do I install clang-analyzer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [main page](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/):

> The analyzer is 100% open source and is **part of the Clang project**. Like the rest of Clang, the analyzer is implemented as a C++ library that can be used by other tools and applications.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

[Download the Clang project](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html) and the analyzer will be included.

Comment: This doesn't explicitly answer my question. I suppose you're saying that if I have clang then I'll have clang-analyzer. Howerver `which clang` shows clang in `/usr/bin/clang`. `which scan-build` comes up empty. Is there another package I need?

Comment: If it's not there, then you should direct your inquiry to the people who actually manage it.  There's a [Clang Developers Mailing List](https://lists.llvm.org/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev) posted on the [Obtaining the Static Analyzer Page](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/installation)

Comment: Your answer at least puts me in the right direction. That official clang-analyzer official installation link I referenced is simply out of date (there aren't separate binary packages for it) and clang itself should be updated and installed. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Glad I could help!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install is to get HomeBrew installed (https://brew.sh if needed), and then have it grab llvm :

```
brew install llvm
```